# Creating Function in C programming, errror in using while loop

Tags: c

Im trying to build a simple book shopping app in C programming. Whenever I chose 2 after chosen 1, it seems like the program has break out from the programming, any advise to improve my code? I want the programming to constantly ask user after choice has been made. A sample program shown as below:

My desire outcome/logic is some sort like this

```
Welcome to Handsome Bookstore
+++++++++++++++++++++++++
Main Menu
1. View
2. Buy
3. Exit
Enter your option (1-3): 4
Invalid! Try again.
Enter your option (1-3): 1
1) C Programming 10.80
2) ANSI C 15.30
3) Problem Solving 12.60
4) How to Program 24.20
Enter your option (1-3): 2
Book title # (1-4)? 5
Invalid! Try again.
Book title # (1-4)? 2
Quantity: 1
Enter your option (1-3): 2
Book title # (1-4)? 1
Quantity: 2
Enter your option (1-3): 3
The total price is RM 36.90
Thank you for using this system
Press any key to continue…
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ROW 4
#define COLUMN 20
#define ROWW 4
#define COLUMNN 5
void View(void);
void Buy(void);
void Exit(void);

int main()
{
    int opt;

    
    printf("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tWelcome To Handsome Bookstore\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t+++++++++++++++++++++++++\n");
    printf("Main menu\n1.View\n2.Buy\n3.Exit\n");
    printf("Enter your option (1-3): ");
    scanf("%d",&opt);
        while(opt<1||opt>3)
        {
            printf("Invalid! Try again.\nEnter your option (1-3): ");
            scanf("%d",&opt);
        }
        if(opt==1)
            {
                View();
                    printf("Enter your option (1-3): ");
                    scanf("%d",&opt);
                while(opt<1||opt>3)
            {
                printf("Invalid! Try again.\nEnter your option (1-3): ");
                scanf("%d",&opt);
        }
        
            }
            else if(opt==2)
            {
                Buy();
            }
            else
            {
                Exit();
            }
}

void View(void)
{
    char name[ROW][COLUMN]={"C Programming","ANSI C","Problem Solving","How to Program"};
    float price[ROWW][COLUMNN]={10.80,15.30,12.60,24.20};
    int x,y,opt;
        for(x=0; x<ROW ;x++)
    {
        printf("%d)", x+1);
            for(y=0; y<COLUMN; y++)
            {   
              printf("%c",name[x][y]);
            }
            printf("\n");
    }
    return;

}
void Buy(void)
{
    int book,quantity;
    printf("Book title # (1-4)? ");
    scanf("%d",&book);
    printf("Quantity:");
    scanf("%d",quantity);
    return;
}
void Exit(void)
{
    float total,book,quantity;
    total=book*quantity;
    printf("The total price is %f\nThank you for using this system",total);
    return;
}
```

Comment: I put an answer indicating your problems and a way to solve and do all, please read it and say me if you understand it

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings and read them

Answer (score 1):

In Buy :

> ```
> scanf("%d",quantity);
> ```

must be

```
scanf("%d",&quantity);
```

else the behavior is undefined ( and generally dramatic )

Note it is also better to check *scanf* returns 1 (see my proposal at the end of the answer).

In Exit :

> ```
>  float total,book,quantity;
>  total=book*quantity;
> ```

*book* and *quantity* are used not initialized, the behavior is undefined

The value you enter in *Buy* are saved in *local variables*, when you leave *Buy* they are lost, you do not got them in *Exit* if this is what you expected

In View :

> ```
> float price[ROWW][COLUMNN]={10.80,15.30,12.60,24.20};
> ```

is useless because *price* is not used, that means it is impossible to have

```
1) C Programming 10.80
2) ANSI C 15.30
3) Problem Solving 12.60
4) How to Program 24.20
```

as you indicate in your question without modifying your code

note also :

> ```
>        for(y=0; y<COLUMN; y++)
>        {   
>          printf("%c",name[x][y]);
>        }
> ```

writes *COLUMN* characters whatever the string, so you write null characters, just do

```
printf("%s", name[x]);
```

and to also have the price :

```
printf("%s %g", name[x], price[x]);
```

redefining price to be for instance :

```
float price[ROWW]={10.80,15.30,12.60,24.20};
```

because it must have 1 dimension

so finally only using one *printf* for all :

```
int x;

for(x=0; x<ROW ;x++)
{
    printf("%d)%s %g\n", x+1, name[x], price[x]);
}
```

Note it is dangerous to have *ROW* and *ROWW* whose can have different value, you want the same number of case, useless to have two sizes, and in fact you do not need to define them

you can have :

```
void View(void)
{
    const char * const name[]={"C Programming","ANSI C","Problem Solving","How to Program"};
    const float price[]={10.80,15.30,12.60,24.20};
    int x;
    
    for(x=0; x < sizeof(name)/sizeof(*name); x++)
    {
      printf("%d)%s %g\n", x+1, name[x], price[x]);
    }
}
```

> I want the programming to constantly ask user after choice has been made

In fact you want something like that, still using the 3 auxiliary functions even there are not very useful and their body can be directly in *main* :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void View(void);
double Buy(void);
void Exit(double);

typedef struct Book {
  const char * name;
  double price;
} Book;

const Book Books[] = {
  { "C Programming", 10.80 },
  { "ANSI C", 15.30 },
  { "Problem Solving", 12.60 },
  { "How to Program", 24.20 }
};

int choice(const char * msg, int min, int max)
{
  for (;;) {
    int n;
    
    fputs(msg, stdout);
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) {
      /* not a number, decide to flush rest of line,
         you can also use getline etc*/
      while ((n = getchar()) && (n != '\n')) {
        if (n == EOF) {
          puts("EOF, abort");
          exit(-1);
        }
      }
    }        
    else if ((n >= min) && ((max < min) || (n <= max)))
      return n;
    
    puts("Invalid! Try again.");
  }
}

int main()
{
  double total = 0;
  
  puts("\tWelcome To Handsome Bookstore\n\t+++++++++++++++++++++++++");
  for (;;) {
    puts("\nMain menu\n1.View\n2.Buy\n3.Exit");
    
    switch (choice("Enter your option (1-3): ", 1, 3)) {
    case 1:
      View();
      break;
    case 2:
      total += Buy();
      break;
    default: /* 3 */
      Exit(total);
      return 0;
    }
  }
}

void View(void)
{
  int x;
  
  for (x=0; x < sizeof(Books)/sizeof(*Books); ++x)
    printf("%d)%s %g\n", x+1, Books[x].name, Books[x].price);
}

double Buy(void)
{
  int book = choice("Book title # (1-4)? ", 1, 4);
  int quantity = choice("Quantity:", 1, 0);
  
  return Books[book].price * quantity;
}

void Exit(double total)
{
  printf("The total price is %f\nThank you for using this system\n", total);
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
    Welcome To Handsome Bookstore
    +++++++++++++++++++++++++

Main menu
1.View
2.Buy
3.Exit
Enter your option (1-3): 4
Invalid! Try again.
Enter your option (1-3): 0 
Invalid! Try again.
Enter your option (1-3): aze
Invalid! Try again.
Enter your option (1-3): 1
1)C Programming 10.8
2)ANSI C 15.3
3)Problem Solving 12.6
4)How to Program 24.2

Main menu
1.View
2.Buy
3.Exit
Enter your option (1-3): 2
Book title # (1-4)? 5
Invalid! Try again.
Book title # (1-4)? 1
Quantity:aze
Invalid! Try again.
Quantity:10

Main menu
1.View
2.Buy
3.Exit
Enter your option (1-3): 2
Book title # (1-4)? 2
Quantity:2

Main menu
1.View
2.Buy
3.Exit
Enter your option (1-3): 3
The total price is 178.200000
Thank you for using this system
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```